# I am trying to start a new react project But I am getting this error and the app is not created. I have installed react globally

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, ubuntu-18.04

[image](base) mukund@mukund-Inspiron-15-3567:~$ create-react-app todo-app

Creating a new React app in /home/mukund/todo-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...{"babel-core":"^6.0.0'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mukund/.npm/_logs/2020-05-10T14_41_17_724Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting todo-app/ from /home/mukund
Done.

Comment: try opening the log file..and share more details description here

Comment: Are you running the latest version of `create-react-app`?

Comment: yes i have the latest version

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the log file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an app like the recommended way by the core React team at [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org) should solve the problem.

Do this:

```
npx create-react-app todo-app
```

If that is still not working then run the following to clear your `npm` cache before trying the step above again:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

This just gives you a clean reset incase your cached modules are conflicting with each other.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you explain why i needed to clean the cache. Also I had react installed globally, still npx installed it. Why?

Comment: I recommend using `npx` just because it's less likely to give environment issues overall. But I think clearing cache was the main fix. Basically if you didn't clear cache, you would have used incompatible package versions in your attempt to build a react project.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes, clearing cache was the main issue. I had used npx earlier. It didn't work. Thanks again